# / not accessible in spring mvc 4

Tags: spring-mvc

I have following classes

AppConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.pdma.dmapp")
public class AppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{

    @Bean(name="multipartResolver")
    public StandardServletMultipartResolver resolver(){
        return new StandardServletMultipartResolver();
    }

    @Override
    public void configureViewResolvers(ViewResolverRegistry registry){
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        registry.viewResolver(viewResolver);
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry){
        registry.addResourceHandler("/webResources/**").addResourceLocations("/webResources/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/angularApps/**").addResourceLocations("/angularApps/");
    }
}
```

SecurityConfiguration.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobalSecurity(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception
    {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser("GISManager")
            .password("gis@manager@pdma")
            .roles("GISManager");

    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
    {
        http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/**").access("hasRole('GISManager')")
            .and().formLogin()
            .and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/Access_Denied");
    }
}
```

AppInitializer.java

```
public class AppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer{

    private static final String LOCATION = "D:/uploads/";
    private static final long MAX_FILE_SIZE = 1024*1024*25;
    private static final long MAX_REQUEST_SIZE = 1024*1024*30;
    private static final int FILE_SIZE_THRESHOLD = 0;

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return new Class [] {AppConfig.class,SecurityConfiguration.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return new String [] {"/",
                              "*.html",
                              "*.htm",
                              "*.ajax"};
    }

    @Override
    protected void customizeRegistration(ServletRegistration.Dynamic registration){
        registration.setMultipartConfig(getMultipartConfigElement());
    }

    private MultipartConfigElement getMultipartConfigElement(){
        MultipartConfigElement element = new MultipartConfigElement(LOCATION,
                                                                    MAX_FILE_SIZE,
                                                                    MAX_REQUEST_SIZE,
                                                                    FILE_SIZE_THRESHOLD);
        return element;
    }

}
```

WelcomeController.java

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/")
public class WelcomeController {

    @GetMapping(value="")
    public String getWelcomePage(){
        return "welcome";
    }
}
```

welcome.jsp is placed in /WEB-INF/views/

I am getting login page and all other pages like main.html etc but I am unable to get welcome page. When I try to hit localhost:8080/dmapp/ I get following message in console:

WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/dmapp/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'

This problem was present before I used spring-security

What can be the problem

Answer (score 0):

changing

```
 @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return new String [] {"/",
                              "*.html",
                              "*.htm",
                              "*.ajax"};
    }
```

to

```
 @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return new String [] {"/"};
    }
```

solved problem in my case